# Java + PL/SQL Call procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to call procedure in PL/SQL from Java.

It is my code in JAVA to call

```
String query = "{CALL zapisz_button(?,?,?)}" ;
        CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall(query); 
        cst.setString(1,txtNazwa.getText());
        cst.setString(2, "test");
        cst.setString(3,txtLiczba.getText());
        cst.execute();
        cst.close();
```

Its is my oracle PL/SQL Procedure

```
create or replace procedure zapisz_button
   (
   nazwaoddzialu IN ODDZIAL.NAZWAODDZIALU%TYPE,
   rodzajoddzialu IN ODDZIAL.RODZAJODDZIALU%TYPE,
   liczbalozek IN ODDZIAL.LICZBALOZEK%TYPE
   )
as
begin 
   insert into ODDZIAL("NAZWAODDZIALU","RODZAJODDZIALU","LICZBALOZEK")
   values (nazwaoddzialu,rodzajoddzialu,liczbalozek);

   commit;
end zapisz_button;
```

I'm looking for the answear where is mistake.
When I am try to add data to database i get an error:

```
java.sql:SQLException: ORA-06550: line1,column7: 
PLS-00201:identifier'ZAPISZ_BUTTON' must be declared 
ORA-06550: line 1,column7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I want to make "Save" to database button using PL/SQL.
I know that i can use just "Insert Into..." but i want to do that in PL/SQL.

Comment: SQL-Server or Oracle SQL?

Comment: Oracle SQL server

Comment: SQL-Server == MSSQL != Oracle SQL

Comment: i use "Oracle SQL"

Comment: "My Call is not working." is not a question.  Please show all error details, and call stack.

Comment: I added information about an error.

Comment: does the procedure belong to the same user that connects in the java program?

Comment: Make sure you include the schema name along with the procedure name. For example, if procedure `ZAPISZ_BUTTON` is defined in the schema `TOMEK` the procedure call would be `"{CALL tomek.zapisz_button(?,?,?)}"`. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot my Friend ! Works perfect !

Comment: Normally you would either define synonyms or else issue an `alter session set current_schema = someschema` at the start of the session to set the default namespace and avoid the need to prefix anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with schema name, please try adding schema name in it and execute.
define your procedure under any package(e.i. package_name) and let's say 'aaa' is the owner of that package.
the procedure call would be .

```
String query = "{CALL aaa.package_name.zapisz_button(?,?,?)}" ;
        CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall(query); 
        cst.setString(1,txtNazwa.getText());
        cst.setString(2, "test");
        cst.setString(3,txtLiczba.getText());
        cst.execute();
        cst.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with schema. It can be handled in different way.

1) Add schema name before your procedure followed by '.'.
2) Create synonym of your procedure in other schema, which is connected with your java application.